# How can I play the background sound in c#

Tags: c#, audio

I already follow the tutorial of adding sound in the c# but it cannot play the sound, but it is no error. How can I do?

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Media;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SoundPlayer myPlayer = new SoundPlayer(WindowsFormsApplication2.Properties.Resources.sound1);
            myPlayer.PlayLooping();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: SoundPlayer only works with WAV files. Is the file you're trying to load a WAV file?

Comment: already add it still no sound

Comment: @user2187491, the question was, ***is it a WAV file?*** You know, the WAV file format.

Comment: I add sound.wav in the resource, it is no error but no sound.

Comment: Is `Form1_Load(...)` called? Maybe you forgot to add the event.

Comment: when I click play on the other program it can play.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the `Form1_Load()` assigned to the Form `Load` event. I've put in your code, and it works just fine.

To assign the event, just look at the following image.[image].

This will ensure that the `Form1_Load()` is called when the form loads.

After having tested to see what would happen when you try to pass a non-.WAV file to the `SoundPlayer`, it WOULD produce an error:

`Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Media.SoundPlayer.SoundPlayer(string)' has some invalid arguments`.

This leads me to believe the code isn't being called.

Comment: A friendly note: It is generally better to try to make sure you understand the exact problem before answering. Sometimes you can get lucky, but other times, not so much.